# Joining multiple tables in a SQL dataset based on their names?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server which contains huge numbers of tables. But each table has 'id' and 'value'. I want to join all the tables which their names contain a certain text (e.g., 'ts2') based on their id (id is a common key). So my desired table should have 'id' and the 'values' of each table with the name of the table. For example:

```
 TableAts2: 
          id,
          value

 TableBts2:
          id,
          value

 Tablts2C:
         id,
         value
         ...
```

My desired table:

```
 mytable:
         id, value_TableAts2,value_TableBts2, value_Tablts2C
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot do this just by joining the tables together?

Comment: The names of all tables must be listed in FROM clause nevertheless. And separate `value` columns for all tables too. You may build desired SQL text by quering INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: There are many tables and these tables may change over time. SO I need to have a query that automatically fetch those table and join them.

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server

Comment: It is SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

Some source datatables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableAts2 (id INT, value INT);
> INSERT INTO TableAts2 VALUES (1,1), (2,2);
> CREATE TABLE TableBts2 LIKE TableAts2;
> INSERT INTO TableBts2 VALUES (1,11), (3,33);
> CREATE TABLE TableCts2 LIKE TableAts2;
> INSERT INTO TableCts2 VALUES (2,222), (3,333);
> ```

Build the query text

> ```
> SELECT
> CONCAT( 'SELECT id, ', 
>         GROUP_CONCAT(table_name, '.value value_',table_name) ,
>         '\nFROM (',
>         GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT id FROM ',table_name SEPARATOR ' UNION '),
>         ') ids\nLEFT JOIN ',
>         GROUP_CONCAT(table_name, ' USING (id)' SEPARATOR '\nLEFT JOIN ')
>       )
> INTO @sql
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
> ```

Check the query built

> ```
> SELECT @sql;
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT id, TableAts2.value value_TableAts2,TableBts2.value value_TableBts2,TableCts2.value value_TableCts2
> FROM (SELECT id FROM TableAts2 UNION SELECT id FROM TableBts2 UNION SELECT id FROM TableCts2) ids
> LEFT JOIN TableAts2 USING (id)
> LEFT JOIN TableBts2 USING (id)
> LEFT JOIN TableCts2 USING (id)
> ```

Execute the query

> ```
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DROP PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> | id | value_TableAts2 | value_TableBts2 | value_TableCts2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 11 | *null* |
> | 2 | 2 | *null* | 222 |
> | 3 | *null* | 33 | 333 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4dc8255a24242b40e6a27cd78cecf0a)*

Of course the query needs in a check that the table contains both `id` and `value` columns (by according subquery to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS).

Comment: Here again I need to mention the name of the tables one by one, which does work in this case. Since the numbers of tables are high and they may increase over time. I need a query that automatically  extract those tables and join them based on their ids (where they have the same id values).

Comment: @TomKlarin I have described both this situation and the solution - look carefully. If your needs are more extended then use my answer as a base and create your own specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work fine for you :

```
select tableAts1.* , TableBts2.* , Tablts2C.*
from tableAts1
inner join TableBts2 on tableAts.id = TableBts2.id
inner join Tablts2C on tableBts2.id = tablts2C.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to insert one column in each table.
For example
TableAts2:
id,
user_id,
value

TableBts2:
id,
user_id,
value

Tablts2C:
id,
user_id,
value
...

Second, you need to join each table with user_id.
Now please run this sql command:

select t.value_TableAts2 as value_TableAts2, t.value_TableBts2 as value_TableBts2, Tablts2C.value as value_Tablts2C from (select TableAts2.value as value_TableAts2, TableBts2.value as value_TableBts2, TableAts2.user_id as user_id from TableAts2 left join TableBts2 on TableAts2.user_id = TableBts2.user_id) as t left join Tablts2C on t.user_id = Tablts2C.user_id

Result :::
Your desired table:
id, value_TableAts2,value_TableBts2, value_Tablts2C